# any suggestions for getting the data for the web portal?

Tags: php, javascript, web-services, web-crawler

I have launched a new Movie Based web portal, I have completed the programming part and Made the site dynamic.
My Question, How can i get the data about the Movies from different languages
For example: www.imdb.com has a huge database collection.
Is there any web crwaling methodology where we can get it?
Or dirty method of Complete Data entry work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The legal approach is to subscribe to IMDB's [web services](http://www.imdb.com/licensing/), which sound pretty comprehensive but cost $15,000 and up.

Another possible datasource that looks free is the [Netflix API](http://developer.netflix.com/).

I'm not going to give you any advice about screen-scraping, both because it will make your life miserable, and because it's almost certainly a violation of copyright laws.

Answer (score 0):

Blockbuster's website has some [RSS feeds](http://www.blockbuster.com/rss) you can scrape, which will contain links to data pages that may or may not be easily scraped as well.